# How do we run git status for a specific remote?

Tags: git, git-remote

We have two remotes for our local git repository. One remote is called `dev`, the other one is called `origin`. When we run `git status` or `git status dev`, we receive this message:

```
# On branch 1.8.x
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/1.8.x' by 4 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

The message tells us the status for the `origin` remote. That isn't what we want. How can we check the status for only the `dev` remote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's *how* `git status` gets that information.

- What branch are we on?

  ```
  $ git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
  1.8.x
  ```

  (the above is the preferred method of finding out, generally; it errors-out if you're in "detached HEAD" mode), or:

  ```
  $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD
  refs/heads/1.8.x
  ```

  (this also works but can only get you the "full name": remove `refs/heads/` to get the branch name).
- What branch is "upstream" of 1.8.x?

  ```
  $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name '@{upstream}'
  refs/remotes/origin/1.8.x
  ```

  (the above is the easier way, but again gives you only the "full name" form; this time you have to remove `refs/remotes/` to shorten it), or:

  ```
  $ git config --get branch.1.8.x.remote
  origin
  $ git config --get branch.1.8.x.merge
  refs/heads/1.8.x
  $ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
  +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  ```

  (this is how git figures out the symbolic-full-name of `@{upstream}`—it's a bit complicated as you have to apply the branch-name mapping from the `fetch` line<sup>1</sup> here).
- How many revisions are there on one side or the other?

  ```
  $ git rev-list --count origin/1.8.x..1.8.x
  4
  $ git rev-list --count 1.8.x..origin/1.8.x
  0
  ```

  That is, we ask `git rev-list` to count how many commits are reachable from reference `1.8.x` (your current branch) but not `origin/1.8.x` (your upstream).  The answer is 4, so you're "ahead 4".  Then we ask `git rev-list` to count how many commits are reachable from `origin/1.8.x` but not from `1.8.x`.  The answer is 0, so you're "behind 0", which `git status` can then be quiet about.

The `git status` command does all this work for whichever branch is set as the current branch's "upstream".  So you can use `git branch --set-upstream-to` to *change* the upstream—in this case, changing it from `origin/1.8.x` to `dev/1.8.x`—and from then on you'll get that information, and *only* that information, from `git status`.  (Change it back to get the information to switch back.)

---

If you want to get it temporarily, without switching branches, you need to do more or less "what `git status` does" but with an alternative "upstream", in this case, `dev/1.8.x`.  It's not that difficult to write a shell script that does this, especially if you simply assume that branch *`B`* maps to branch *`rmt/B`* for the given remote *`rmt`* (then you need not do all the complicated mapping).  That is, if you're on branch `zog`, and you're asking about remote `bob`, you just do the two `rev-list`s for `bob/zog..zog` and `zog..bob/zog`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, you'd really want `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` in case there are multiple ref-mapping `fetch` lines.  But this ref-mapping is a pain; probably there should be a git plumbing command to do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

You may use "git log", it'll list the commits ahead if any.

```
git log dev/1.8.x..HEAD
```

or

```
git log dev/1.8.x..1.8.x
```

If you'd like more brief info, you may try:

```
git log --graph --pretty=oneline dev/1.8.x..HEAD
```